# Visualisation of clusters returned by Kmeans

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, plotly

I used KMeans for clustering as shown below, but I don't know to visualize  clusters like shown in the figure below to see the satisfaction of the customer. 
[image: example]

code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score

documents = ["This little kitty came to play when I was eating at a          restaurant.",
         "Merley has the best squooshy kitten belly.",
         "Google Translate app is incredible.",
         "If you open 100 tab in google you get a smileyface.",
         "Best cat photo I've ever taken.",
         "Climbing ninja cat.",
         "Impressed with google map feedback.",
         "Key promoter extension for Google Chrome."]

  vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
  X = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

 true_k = 3
 model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++',  max_iter=100,n_init=1)
 model.fit(X)
```

Comment: The graph and the code don't seem to match. The graph looks like sentiment analysis but the code shows unsupervised clustering. Can you explain your desired outcome in more detail?

Comment: I have text of feedback of clients in one firm .. I want to do such this graph with doing clustering .. AM i clear now?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Via words employed in the feedbacks of my clients i want to have this analysis.

Comment: You want a pie chart of the proportions of samples in each of the 3 partitions that k-means returns? Just note that as the partitioning is unsupervised, you won't be able to know with cluster corresponds to which type of feedback.

Comment: @Eskapp for example if we have feedbacks like :'good, enjoyabe, funny, rich, satitisfull ... ' we can say that the most of clients are satistied

Comment: @Eskapp do you propose something? in this case please

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that you have a way to know which partition of k-means represents which sentiment, you can plot a pie chart as follows:

```
print(model.labels_)  # For illustration, you can see which sentence is in which cluster
# Here we get the proportions
nb_samples = [sum(model.labels_ == j) for j in range(true_k)]

# On the next line the order is RANDOM. I do NOT know which cluster represents what.
# The first label should represent samples in cluster 0, and so on
labels = 'positive', 'neutral', 'negative'
colors = ['gold', 'red', 'lightblue']  # Same size as labels

# Pie chart
plt.pie(nb_samples, labels=labels, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Also not, that several runs will give you different results in terms of which cluster represents which category.

This can be avoided by setting the numpy random seed.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)  # Or any other integer
```

Comment: @EskappThank you for your response .. Im new with text mining, If i understant your remark .. Positive a negative in this case are just labels.. And we don't know if the feedback is really positive or negative?

Comment: @anayisse2 As you use unsupervised clustering, you cannot know which cluster/partition corresponds to which class of feedback except if you go see yourself the sentences that belong to that cluster/partition. This is out of the scope of programming and I suggest you to read about the differences between supervised and unsupervised approaches as it is a core concept of machine learning. You can start here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2907/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-supervised-and-unsupervised-learning